# How can I copy files with the directory structure?

Tags: ruby, copy, rake

Is there a way I can copy files with their directory structure?

Here is what I have:

```
  files = FileList.new()
  files.include("#{HOST_DIR}/**/bin/*.dll")
  files.include("#{HOST_DIR}/**/bin/*.pdb")
  files.include("#{HOST_DIR}/**/bin/*.xml")
  files.include("#{HOST_DIR}/**/bin/**/*.xml")
  files.include("#{HOST_DIR}/**/TestData/*.*")
  FileUtils.cp(files,'c:/temp',:verbose => true)
```

It copies all files to one folder `c:/temp`. I would like the files to keep the directory structure in `#{HOST_DIR}`.

**UPDATE**:

I got a solution:

```
 files.each do |file|
    target = file.sub(SERVICEHOST_DIR,'c:/temp')
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(target))    
    FileUtils.cp_r(file,target,:verbose => true)
  end
```

Is there a better one?

Answer (score 0):

I think [FileUtils#cp_r](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/FileUtils.html#M001774) should do the trick.

```
dest = 'c:/temp'

files = Dir.chdir(HOST_DIR) do
  Dir.glob %w' **/bin/*.dll
               **/bin/*.pdb
               **/bin/*.xml
               **/bin/**/*.xml
               **/TestData/*.*
             '
end

FileUtils.cp_r files, dest, :verbose => true
```